# ScaLAPACK, "Semaphore timeout period has expired" while calling Cblacs_gridinit()

Tags: c, mpi, scalapack

I use ScaLAPACK from Intel MKL, with MPICH2 installed over a network of Windows 7 computers. It works fine when I run jobs on single machine, like:

```
mpiexec -n 16 Z:/myprogram.exe       # Z:/ is a mapped network drive
```

Moreover, it works fine over network when I run `cpi.exe` (the test program delivered along with MPICH2):

```
mpiexec -hosts 4 host1 4 host2 4 ... Z:/cpi.exe
```

My code (solution of big linear equations) also works fine on single machine. However, it fails when I do:

```
mpiexec -hosts 2 host1 8 host2 8 Z:/myprogram.exe
```

The message is:

```
Fatal error in PMPI_Comm_create: Other MPI error, error stack:
PMPI_Comm_create(609)................: MPI_Comm_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, group=0x8
8000001, new_comm=001DF644) failed
PMPI_Comm_create(590)................:
MPIR_Comm_create_intra(250)..........:
MPIR_Get_contextid(521)..............:
MPIR_Get_contextid_sparse(683).......:
MPIR_Allreduce_impl(712).............:
MPIR_Allreduce_intra(197)............:
allreduce_intra_or_coll_fn(106)......:
MPIR_Allreduce_intra(357)............:
MPIC_Sendrecv(192)...................:
MPIC_Wait(540).......................:
MPIDI_CH3I_Progress(402).............:
MPID_nem_mpich2_blocking_recv(905)...:
MPID_nem_newtcp_module_poll(37)......:
MPID_nem_newtcp_module_connpoll(2656):
gen_cnting_fail_handler(1739)........: connect failed - Semaphore timeout period has expired. (errno 121)

job aborted:
rank: node: exit code[: error message]
0: 10.30.10.182: 1: process 0 exited without calling finalize
1: 10.30.10.184: 123
2: 10.30.10.184: 123
3: 10.30.10.184: 123
4: 10.30.10.184: 123
5: 10.30.10.184: 123
6: 10.30.10.184: 123
7: 10.30.10.184: 123
8: 10.30.10.184: 123
9: 10.30.10.184: 123
10: 10.30.10.184: 123
11: 10.30.10.184: 123
12: 10.30.10.184: 123
13: 10.30.10.184: 123
14: 10.30.10.184: 123
15: 10.30.10.184: 123
```

From what I know now, the problem occurs at early beginning of my C code:

```
Cblacs_pinfo(&mype, &npe); // OK, gets correct values
Cblacs_get(-1, 0, &icon); // OK, gets correct value
Cblacs_gridinit(&icon, "c", mp, np); // Never returns from this line.
```

I would be grateful for any help or advice. Solving this issue is of high importance to me.

EDIT: The code below does work, so my MPI infrastructure seems OK..?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

 int numprocs, rank, namelen;
 char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
 printf("start\n");

 MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
 MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
 MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
 MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &namelen);

 printf( "Process %d on %s out of %d\n" , rank, processor_name, numprocs);

 MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: are you calling `MPI_Init`, `MPI_Comm_rank` before the 3 `Cblacs` calls?

Comment: also can  you print the value of `&icon` after your `Cblacs_get` call?

Comment: @pyCthon Regarding your questions: 1) No, the three lines I posted are the first MPI-related commands. 2) icon is equal zero on all nodes.

Comment: @pyCthon, ones does not need to call `MPI_Init()` with ScaLAPACK as `Cblacs_pinfo()` takes care for the proper MPI initialisation.

Comment: @HristoIliev yeah but you still can initialize MPI yourself instead of letting Cblacs handle it